# Rust used to have a ton of pointer types; what were they, and what happened to each one?

Tags: rust

Rust used to have a ton of pointer types:

> Older Rusts had many more pointer types, they’re gone now.
>
> — https://doc.rust-lang.org/guide-pointers.html

I'm looking to understand the chronology of some of them to understand the language's evolution a little more deeply.

Q1: What were they? Are there previous versions of the Rust docs online that I can look at or do I have to recompile the old docs to do so?

Q2: What became of each pointer type as the language evolved (e.g. became redundant, functionality merged someplace else, dropped as a feature, etc.)?

Comment: I would recommend to look at release notes, specifically sections for versions [0.11](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/RELEASES.md#version-0110-2014-07-02) and [0.12](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/RELEASES.md#version-0120-2014-10-09). Several types of pointers became standard library structures instead of built-in language features, and `@`/`Gc` was removed altogether.

Answer (score 9):

From the archive of the guide:
[image: screenshot of cheat sheet]

Interestingly, it appears that Rust used to call Box, Rc, and Arc pointer types. So, unfortunately, it seems like the pointer types that the guide was claiming Rust once had are actually still in the language. However, that doesn't mean there still isn't a story behind these types. Rust actually used to have [two different box types](https://tomlee.co/2012/12/managed-and-owned-boxes-in-the-rust-programming-language/), `~T` and `@T`, but these were [removed in version 0.11.0](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/RELEASES.md#version-0110-2014-07-02) in favor of `Box` and `Gc`, respectively (believe it or not Rust actually had a garbage collector back then). In the [1.0.0 alpha](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/RELEASES.md#version-100-alpha-2015-01-09), the `box` keyword (which has been in the language from as early as 0.1.0) was feature-gated for a redesign, [and the discussion is still happening to this day](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/49733). After that change, no real major changes happened to `Box` except for a couple extra trait implementations and method additions.

Now, for Arc and Rc. `Arc` appears to have been added [as early as version 0.3](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/RELEASES.md#version-03--2012-07-12), and `Rc` was [added in version 0.7](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/RELEASES.md#version-07-2013-07-03). Also, unlike modern Rust, `Rc` did not have a way to get a mutable reference, and they instead opted for [having both `Rc` and `RcMut`](https://static.rust-lang.org/doc/0.7/extra/rc.html). `Arc` was even weirder, having an immutable `ARC`, a `MutexARC` (instead of the current `Arc<Mutex<T>>`), [and a mutable `RWARC`](https://static.rust-lang.org/doc/0.7/extra/arc.html#function-rwarc). In [version 0.8](https://static.rust-lang.org/doc/0.8/extra/arc/index.html), despite not being in the changelogs for whatever reason, [`ARC` finally got lowercased to `Arc`](https://static.rust-lang.org/doc/0.8/extra/arc/index.html). In [version 0.9](https://static.rust-lang.org/doc/0.9/std/rc/index.html), more undocumented changes happened where `Rc` was moved from the extra crate to std, and `RcMut` was mysteriously removed. An `UnsafeArc` was added into `std::sync::arc`, but `extra::arc::Arc` remained. In [version 0.10](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/RELEASES.md#version-010-2014-04-03), `Weak` was added for cycle breaking, and prior to that version, Rust surprisingly tried to statically prevent `Rc` cycles. In [version 0.11.0](https://static.rust-lang.org/doc/0.11.0/std/sync/index.html), sweeping changes were made to `Arc`, separating `Arc` and `Mutex`, but `Arc` was still immutable and relied on `Arc<RWLock<T>>` to simulate `Arc`'s current behavior. Strangely enough, `Rc` was **still** immutable. In [version 1.0.0](https://static.rust-lang.org/doc/1.0.0/std/rc/fn.get_mut.html), `Rc` finally got the `get_mut` method we know and love. However, `Arc` still depended on `RwLock`. `Arc` was a bit slower, getting [an unstable `get_mut` function in 1.3.0](https://static.rust-lang.org/doc/1.3.0/std/sync/struct.Arc.html).

And now, the interesting one. What happened to `Gc`? It was removed [in version 0.12](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/RELEASES.md#version-0120-2014-10-09) due to being [poorly implemented, confusing, and the only reason why many obsolete language features existed at the time](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/256), with the promise that a garbage collector would be revisited in the future. As we know now, that never happened.

As for if you can see old docs, yes you can. They're all hosted at `static.rust-lang.org`. Just go to `https://static.rust-lang.org/doc/VERSION_NUMBER/CRATE_NAME/index.html`, such as https://static.rust-lang.org/doc/0.7/std/index.html.

Comment: FWIW Rust called them "pointer types" because as can be seen from the syntax they were special buit-ins of the language. Though `Box` remains special-cased, the old pointer types were embedded much deeper into the language, rather like references still are.

Comment: "believe it or not Rust actually had a garbage collector back then" technically no more so than today, as the removal note indicates the "Gc" type (and the corresponding poiter) was just reference counted, implementing a proper Gc had been in the plans from the start, but got dropped alongside `Gc` itself.